# Put data from JSON file in a listview and bind them to a grid in xaml

Tags: c#, json, xaml, listview, xamarin

I have a `DetailPage` where I have put a `ContenView` into. In this `ContenView` I implemented a `Grid` because I wanted something like `Refresh-Button` for the JSON-ListView. That worked really well so far.

With your help I've accomplished to parse the JSON Data and put it into a `ListView`. My plan was to put this `ListView` in the 2nd row of my first `Grid`. I did another `Grid` in the first `Grid` where I tried to push the `ListView` inside, but the fields are empty...

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Lqt.jpg

Here is my XAML Code from the DetailPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ODC_Foto_ConWin_v1.YardList"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ODC_Foto_ConWin_v1"
             Title="YardList"
             BackgroundColor="LightGray">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="#004d93">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="File-Age: &lt; 12m" FontSize="Small" Margin="5,5,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            <Image Source="sync.png" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Scale="0.7" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="0" Text="Sync" FontSize="Small" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" Margin="0,5,5,0" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="Transparent" VerticalOptions="Center" Clicked="yardListSyncButton_Clicked"/>
            <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ListView x:Name="listViewJson">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding id}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding kfz_nr}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding kfz_kz}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding timestamp}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="ProgressLoader" IsVisible="True" IsRunning="True"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Icon="add.png" Activated="ToolbarItem_Activated"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
</ContentPage>
```

and here is my C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ODC_Foto_ConWin_v1
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class YardList : ContentPage
    {
        public YardList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetJSON();
        }

        private void yardListSyncButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetJSON();
        }

        private void ToolbarItem_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // code for manual process
        }

        public async void GetJSON()
        {
            var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://x.x.x.x/xample.JSON");
            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            RootObject rootObject = new RootObject();
            ListView listViewJson = new ListView();
            if (json != "")
            {
                rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
            }
            listViewJson.ItemsSource = rootObject.process;
            ProgressLoader.IsVisible = false;
        }

        public class Process
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string fzg_nr { get; set; }
            public string fzg_kz { get; set; }
            public string timestamp { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public string file_timestamp { get; set; }
            public List<Process> process { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this something about wrong DataBinding? Am I initiating the ItemSource at the wrong point?! Because when I set the datatemplate in the `GetJSON()` method the data is visible...
So far i tried a few examples but at some point there must be a little mistake. I am new programming (I'm normally a systemadministrator) so I don't where to start looking for the mistakes.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: don't create new list, use existing one - just remove `ListView listViewJson = new ListView();` from GetJSON and it should work.

**Long answer**

In your XAML you have:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewJson">
```

and in your GetJSON method you are creating **NEW** ListView and setting ItemSource like this:

```
public async void GetJSON()
{
    ListView listViewJson = new ListView();
    (...)
    listViewJson.ItemsSource = rootObject.process;       
}
```

So you have 2 ListViews, one in XAML, and one in GetJSON method. Your ListView in XAML has the same name like ListView in GetJSON method (`listViewJson`). Because ListView created in method is 'closer' in line `listViewJson.ItemsSource = rootObject.process` then ListView created in XAML,you are setting ItemSource of newly created ListView that was not added to your ContentView.

EDIT:
I see couple other minor issues in your code, not related to the question but because you are learning, I thing it's worth to point them out:

- Labels in your ListView template do not have Grid as direct parent so `Grid.Column="0"` does not have any effect

  ```
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                 <Label Grid.Column="0">
  ```
- In C# it is a common practice to use PascalCase naming style for properties. I think that you did this: `public string timestamp { get; set; }` because of json format. You can use `JsonPropertyAttribute` to set your mapping between C# and json like this:

  ```
  [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
  public string Timestamp { get; set; }
  ```
- You are hiding `ProgressLoader` at the end of `GetJSON` but you are not  showing it at the beginning, so it is visible only on your fist `GetJSON` call (so in constructor).
- now your are using code behind and it is totally ok when you are starting with Xamarin. Later on I would suggest you go take a look at MVVM pattern.

Comment: You were right. Thank you so much! I also took the other recommendentions from you. Thank you!!!!